# Populating data to individual columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the data from the list (list_addresses) and populate it to different columns of the dataframe (dfloc). I use the below code, not sure where I am going wrong.

Values are present in list_addresses but not getting populated to the dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
for index in range(len(list_addresses)):
 location = geolocator.reverse([list_addresses[index][0],list_addresses[index][1]])
 dfloc.loc[dfloc.Latitude] = list_addresses[index][0]
 dfloc.loc[dfloc.Longitude] = list_addresses[index][1]
 dfloc.loc[dfloc.Address] = location.address
```

Comment: Try remove second `dfloc` - `dfloc.loc['Latitude'] = list_addresses[index][0]` or `dfloc['Latitude‌​'] = list_addresses[index‌​][0]`

Comment: @jezrael: I tried this previously, it didnot work. But when i print the values of the list, it prints out correctly.

Comment: It is problematic testing, because I have no data. Is possible add some samples - `dfloc`, `list_addresses`, if important explain `geolocator.reverse`. I think you can try simplify your problem for better testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you have a list of lists or tuples with form of [(Lat1,Lon1),(Lat2,Lon2), etc...].  I like to make a list for each column, then assign the entire column at once:

```
lat_list = [x[0] for x in list_addresses]
lon_list = [x[1] for x in list_addresses]
address_list = []

for index in range(len(list_addresses)):
    location = geolocator.reverse([list_addresses[index][0],list_addresses[index][1]])
    address_list.append(location.address)        

dfloc['Latitude'] = lat_list
dfloc['Longitude'] = lon_list
dfloc['Address'] = address_list
```